# Outlook for Mac 2011: keyboard shortcut to accept meeting invite (respond without comments)

Tags: outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if there was a keyboard shortcut in Outlook for Mac 2011 to accept a meeting invite? Specifically, how can I "respond without comments" by only using the keyboard?

I found this, but only has task accepts: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-HP001230396.aspx

Comment: i've been trying to figure this out too. Looks like maybe no such?

Comment: Best I've been able to find is mouse-keys in Karabiner.

Comment: still no better in Outlook for Mac 2016!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in Mac OS X keyboard shortcuts mechanism to program a keyboard shortcut to accept.

1. Open `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`
2. Add a new entry for "Microsoft Outlook".
3. The menu option you want is `Meeting->Accept->Do Not Send a Response` (no quotes, do NOT put a space before or after the arrows.

Pro-tip: -> lets you drill down into a submenu).

Comment: I was attempting to set this up and found the menu option available in Outlook 16, after I went to system preferences and back to Outlook I could no longer find it. I think it was originally under the Message menu, but now it is nowhere. So I think the reason it sometimes doesn't work for you is if the menu option is missing it won't work. Does anybody know what triggers the menu option to hide or show?

Comment: Well... it seems like it has to do with how the sender formulated the meeting/message. If it is a meeting it shows the meeting menu, but if it came as  a message it does not (double click to open in its own window, then click "Meeting" button on the message to see the menu change, but now it's creating a new item so this isn't really that helpful :(

Comment: I don't see a "Meeting" menu...

Comment: As of outlook 16 (Circa 2023) the menu option is 
Event->Accept->Respond Without Comments